# ListView displays items twice

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a listview in flutter with the following :

The expected functionality is the listview should display 1 item at a time.

```
class SimpleContentScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleContentScreenState createState() => _SimpleContentScreenState();
}

class _SimpleContentScreenState extends BaseState<SimpleContentScreen> {

  List<SimpleContent> simpleContentList;
  List<SimpleContent> displayList = List();
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    simpleContentList = getOOFirstContent();
    displayList.add(simpleContentList[_currentIndex]);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar("Introduction"),
      body: _buildListView(),
      floatingActionButton: _buildFab(),
    );
  }

  FloatingActionButton _buildFab() => FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if( _currentIndex < simpleContentList.length - 1 ) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = _currentIndex + 1;
          displayList.add(simpleContentList[_currentIndex]);
        });
      }
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
  );

  ListView _buildListView() => ListView.builder(
      key: Key("_simple_content_list"),
      itemCount: displayList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
        return _buildItemView( displayList[position] );
      }
  );

  _buildItemView(SimpleContent displayList) => Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 32, 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueAccent),
      child : new Text(
          displayList.contentString,
          style: buildTextSimpleContent(20))
  );


}
```

Upon press of FAB - it's adding the items twice. Why is this? I have solved it by clearing the displayList and adding all items from 0 to the current index.

I tried setting key to the listview, but that didn't solve it.

Any help or insight appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` calls the `build` method of the Widget to build

So this is what's happening

`onPressed` method is called when FAB is clicked

```
_currentIndex = _currentIndex + 1;
displayList.add(simpleContentList[_currentIndex]);
```

This adds a new item

But then `build` method is again called
So you again add the element in the list in build method `displayList.add(simpleContentList[_currentIndex]);`

## Solution 1

Remove

```
simpleContentList = getOOFirstContent();
displayList.add(simpleContentList[_currentIndex]);
```

from `build` and add it to `initState`

## Solution 2

delete

```
displayList.add(simpleContentList[_currentIndex]);
```

from `setState` so that the element is added only once

For more details on StateFul Widget Lifecycle method refer [here](https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/)

Comment: Thanks @Mangaldeep Pannu, that helped.